# Heat map in ArcGIS Pro based on attributes not density

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, heat-map

I am trying to create a heat map based on point attribute values, not density.

Do you know how to do this?

I have tried making heat maps, then using kernel density selecting the attribute as my weighted value but the scale does not match and does not even come close to the min and max values of my attribute point data.  Heat map based on attribute values not density calculation.

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking interpolation rather than heat map ? what kind of result are you looking for ?

Comment: Boss is looking for a heat map showing where "hot/cold" values are but wants to see a scale that represents the values not ca calculated density if that makes sense

Comment: So it seem to me that your boss will be happy with an interpolated map (look at IDW)

Comment: Thank you!  I will take a look at IDW.  Thanks again!